# How to obtain inverse result of d3-ease interpolation?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, easing

d3-ease allows to interpolate a particular value dependently on time entered.

```
var dx = d3.easeCubicOut(t)
```

However, what if **vise verse** I need to detect which particular moment the function would equal to some provide value. In other words, I don't need to know how far will the ball be at a particular moment, but **when** it will be in let's say 0.75 of its normalized path length.

Something like this:

```
var dt = d3.easeCubicOut_viseVerse(dx)
```

Is there any standard/easy way to handle that?

Comment: The d3-ease docs give all the details about the function, which is just a very simple cubic function. From there, finding its inverse should take about 30 seconds, it's very simple maths. However if you want a generic solution for any of those easing functions, then it's probably going to be more complex, as you'll have to solve it numerically. Also some of those functions would yield multiple solutions for some values.

Comment: @jcaron, yes. You always can go to sources and create your own reverse. But it's like saying that "you don't need any frameworks, as they just use general logic". That's weird that d3 doesn't have the reverses implemented.

Comment: @altocumulus, right. Looks like almost the same. It's strange Google didn't help me before that. Thanks!

Comment: @Agat you probably didn't find my answer in Google because the title of that question is not the best one. Your question's title, for instance, describes the problem better.